# Sending parameter to different Controller dependent of Context

Tags: jsf, jsf-2

I need to send the value of an input field to different controllers depending of the Context the JSF is called.

The JSF that holds the input field is included in an other JSF.

Example:
I have a View that displays a User and the addresses that belong to that user. I have a controller for the user page and an according JSF. That JSF includes an other JSF that is supposed to show the table of the addresses. The addresses JSF has an input field with which the user can choose how the table is supposed to look like.

I also want to use the addresses JSF on the page that shows customers.

My Problem is now, that I dont know where to send the value of the input field in the addresses table. If I send it to the User Controller I cant use the table with customers an vice versa.

I would like to store the value of the input field in the Controller of the JSF that is including the addresses JSF. (Except someone has a better idea)

How can I implement that functionallity without having to write a table-JSF for every page that includes it?

Some code:

```
<ui:include src="/model/person/personList.xhtml">
            <ui:param name="renderMode" value="#{UserController.renderMode}"></ui:param>
            <ui:param name="persons" value="#{user.persons}"></ui:param>
        </ui:include>
```

The in the code its about persons, but its the same problem.
I'm passing down the parameter, this parameter I would like to be able to change in the included JSF an pass it back to the controller.

Comment: actually I've made no progress in solving this problem, any code I can provide just shows how I'm including the JSF. I'm stuck with this problem in the conceptual stage.

Comment: Added code. Are the parameters passed down by value or by reference? The variable is an int.

Comment: I totally fail to see your actual problem. You already seem to be passing something in. You can also pass a controller in via a param. So please be way more specific about the actual issue. Show the include file

Comment: I think you just solved my problem, i didn't know you could pass a controller via parameter. I have to try it out to see if it works.